# iOS8 RSSI and Proximity unexpected results

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I am using CoreLocation to detect 4 specific beacons in my classroom, unfortunately, no matter how I move and how close I am to the beacon, CoreLocation provides me with `proximity: 0, +/- -1.00m` and `RSSI: 0`.

The code in my controller is this:

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn){
            print("Powered on")
        }
        else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff){
            print("Powered off")
        }
        else if(central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unknown){
            print("Unknown state")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(advertisementData)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        var knownBeacons = beacons.filter{$0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown}
        if(knownBeacons.count > 0){
            closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        }

        print(beacons)

        for beacon in beacons{
            print(beacon.proximity.rawValue)
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** After some debugging I found out that the methods `didConnectPeripheral` and `didDiscoverPeripheral` are not being called by iOS on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

In case you correctly print out the `CLBeacon` information, one problem can be the advertising frequency of the beacons you have. If they broadcast at a very low frequency (once per second or less), then iOS will have a hard time figuring out accurate values for RSSI and proximity.

Regarding your `CBCentralManager` question, you have to explicitly call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:` to start the scan and then `stopScan`. You want to call `stopScan` for at least two reasons: scanning drains battery and after a couple of seconds you will receive all the information you need about the BLE peripherals around you. You can stop the scan with a timer or manually from UI. After you've received the information about the peripherals, then you can issue connect on them. Only then you'll get notification on `didConnectPeripheral` delegate method.

Comment: The problem is that my MacBook's BeaconScanner can find them, same with other BTLE utilities on iPhone, so I suppose there must be an error in my code?

Thank you for your elaboration on the `CBCentralManager`!

Comment: And you suggest I look for services, for example the serviceUUID to collect the RSSI?